# I messed up ocamlfuse by using sudo command "Error: Sqlite3 error: READONLY"

Tags: mount, sudo, read-only, google-drive, sqlite3

I started using ocamlfuse to access google drive with Nautilus and it was functioning perfectly fine. The thing is, at some point I used, by accident, the sudo command, I'm not shure if it was to run ocamlfuse:

```
sudo google-drive-ocamlfuse
```

Or if I used it when mounting the folder

```
sudo google-drive-ocamlfuse ~/googledrive
```

After that, I can only mount the googledrive folder with the sudo command, and if I run

```
google-drive-ocamlfuse
```

I get this:

"Error: Sqlite3 error: READONLY"

Accessing just by using the sudo command gives me trouble when trying to open multiple documents with Libreoffice and some other applications at the same time.

Comment: I would start by checking (and correcting if necessary) the ownership of the configuration files described here: [Configuration](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse/wiki/Configuration)

Comment: Ownership from the files is ok, and apparently changing their permissons didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I solved this by just removing the package using purge and autoremove. I also erased the .gdfuse folder in home so I could do a clean installation. The problem was solved doing this, in case someone wants to know.

Answer (score 4):

Run:

sudo chown -R your-username.your-username ~/.gdfuse

This will change the permissions of ~/.gdfuse/default/cache/cache.db back to your user's and then you can perform the command.